# To use Wordpress themes in Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Wordpress themes are beautiful!

Is there any guideline to use Wordpress themes in a rails app? Even better, are there rails app templates which can use the Wordpress themes already?

Thanks!

Comment: it would be great if there was an easy way to do this. after all it is just html, js and css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the [install_theme gem](http://drnicwilliams.com/2009/10/06/install-any-html-themetemplate-into-your-rails-app/). I haven't it used it but it's supposed to make it easy to install other themes into a Rails app.

Comment: That gem doesn't install Wordpress themes, which is the original question.  It will install a plain HTML theme.

Answer (score 4):

WordPress themes consist CSS, images, and templates that are mix of HTML and PHP (with the PHP invoked WordPress APIs). There's nothing for Rails that I know of that will deal directly with WordPress templates.

However, reusing CSS and images from WordPress with HTML that you generate from Rails instead of from WordPress is quite straightforward. If it's hard to tell what HTML will be generated from the .php bits, load the theme up in a scratch copy of WordPress, and view the source of the generated pages to see the generated structure. Then generate the same in Rails. That's about it (after you adjust paths for the .css and image locations).

One issue worth noting is giving credit for the theme. It's customary in WordPress to leave credits in the footer. It'd be good form to leave these in when you convert a theme to Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Did not find an easy solution to this so I created a gem: https://github.com/lfender6445/theme_bandit

```
gem install theme_bandit
```

It's a work in progress, but the gem allows you to build a tiny rack application out of an existing live site. If nothing else, this will do a large portion of the setup work when converting an existing template to a ruby project (handling of assets like js, css, and conversion for template engines)